# SQL Server Query against a View failing

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a view definition that references a linked JDE server. Querying the view is now giving some very strange results. If I perform a *SELECT ** I get all the results (619 rows) back but if I try *SELECT TOP 1000 ** or query for each column individually I get the following error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the suggestions. It turned out to be a data issue where someone has added codes *A*, *G*, and *R* to the JDE table used to hydrate a relationship that requires an *int* code in SQL Server. It doesn't explain the weird behaviour but it does address it.

Comment: And the view looks like...?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you need to run [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx)

See this on SO ["“select * from table” vs “select colA, colB, etc. from table” interesting behaviour in SQL Server 2005"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321468/select-from-table-vs-select-cola-colb-etc-from-table-interesting-behavio/323103#323103)

Comment: +1 I thought that only oracle has so problems. :). Ms is growing up to the level of oracle and does the same mistakes. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - It didn't help (see my comment above) but I'll keep it in mind for future reference.